# Smooth scrolling text in Qlabel

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qwidget, qlabel

I am trying to use a Qlabel as a message center for relaying messages to users of the application. Some messages might be longer than allowed for the Qlabel and I want it to just scroll horizontally until the end of the text. How can I do this in a Qlabel? I cannot seem to find anything in designer and don't want to work out some sort of truncation method in code that just takes off pieces from the front of the string, that seems silly.

Comment: Do you want it to scroll automatically, like one of those lighted signs?  Or you just want the user to be able to scroll it?

Comment: Lighted signs. Definitely. Don't want anyone to be able to move it.

Answer (score 4):

What you are after is commonly known as Marquee widget. Here is a very simple and rusty implementation which make use of a `QLabel`, but it can be done with a `QWidget` too. I overridden the setText method from which i use a `QTextDocument`, with parent the `QLabel` itself, which holds the text. If the text is bigger than the size of the `QLabel` a `QTimer` triggers a translation method that moves the text:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QTimer, pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QPainter, QFontMetrics
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication


class Marquee(QLabel):

    x = 0

    paused = False
    document = None
    speed = 50
    timer = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.fm = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        self.setFixedSize(200, 20)

    def setText(self, value):
        self.x = 0

        self.document = QTextDocument(self)
        self.document.setPlainText(value)
        # I multiplied by 1.06 because otherwise the text goes on 2 lines
        self.document.setTextWidth(self.fm.width(value) * 1.06)
        self.document.setUseDesignMetrics(True)

        if self.document.textWidth() > self.width():
            self.timer = QTimer(self)
            self.timer.timeout.connect(self.translate)
            self.timer.start((1 / self.speed) * 1000)

    @pyqtSlot()
    def translate(self):
        if not self.paused:
            if self.width() - self.x < self.document.textWidth():
                self.x -= 1
            else:
                self.timer.stop()
        self.repaint()

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.paused = True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.paused = False
        return super().event(event)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.document:
            p = QPainter(self)
            p.translate(self.x, 0)
            self.document.drawContents(p)
        return super().paintEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Marquee()
    w.setText('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit...')
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1):

With a little bit changing **@Daniele Pantaleone**'s code.I have implemented 3 mode of
Animations

i.e **Left-to-Right,Right-to-Left & Left+Right** .

It also supports **Text Color** and Marquee only work if text length exceeds the  Label width.

Here is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QEvent, QTimer, pyqtSlot,QRectF
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QPainter, QFontMetrics,QFont,QColor,QAbstractTextDocumentLayout,QPalette
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLabel, QApplication


class Document(QTextDocument):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def drawContents(self, p, rect=QRectF()):
        p.save()
        ctx=QAbstractTextDocumentLayout.PaintContext ()
        ctx.palette.setColor(QPalette.Text, p.pen().color())
        if (rect.isValid()) :
            p.setClipRect(rect)
            ctx.clip = rect
        self.documentLayout().draw(p, ctx)
        p.restore()
class Marquee(QLabel):
    paused = False
    speed = 60
    x=0
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.document = None
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.translate)
    def setText(self, value,mode="LR"):
        f=self.font()
        self.fm=QFontMetrics(f)
        if self.document is  None:
            self.document = Document(self)
            self.document.setUseDesignMetrics(True)
        self.document.setDefaultFont(f)
        self.document.setDocumentMargin(0)
        
        if self.timer.isActive() :
            self.timer.stop()
        if self.fm.width(value)  > self.width():
            self.nl = int(self.width()/self.fm.horizontalAdvance(" "))
            val=' '*self.nl +value+' '*self.nl 
            self.document.setTextWidth(self.fm.width(val)+22 )
            self.document.clear()
            self.document.setPlainText(val)
            self.setMode(mode)
            self.timer.start((1 / 60) * 1000)
        else:
            self.x=(self.width()/2)-(self.fm.width(value)/2)
            self.document.clear()
            self.document.setPlainText(value)
            self.repaint()
    
    def setMode(self,val):
        if val=="RL":
            self.x = 0
        elif val=="LR"  :  
            self.x =-(self.document.textWidth()-self.fm.width(" "*self.nl)-10)
        else:
            self.x =-(self.document.textWidth()-self.fm.width(" "*self.nl)-10)
            self.fstr=True    
        self.mode=val 
    @pyqtSlot()
    def translate(self):
        if not self.paused:
            if self.mode=="RL":
                if self.width() - self.x < self.document.textWidth():
                    self.x -= 1   
                else:
                    self.x=0
            elif  self.mode=="LR"  :
                if self.x<=0:
                    self.x+= 1 
                else:   
                    self.x =-(self.document.textWidth()-self.fm.width(" "*self.nl)-10)
            else:
                if self.fstr:
                    if self.x<=0:
                        self.x+= 1 
                    else:   
                        self.x =0
                        self.fstr=False
                else:
                    if self.width() - self.x < self.document.textWidth():
                        self.x -= 1   
                    else:
                        self.x=-(self.document.textWidth()-self.fm.width(" "*self.nl)-10)
                        self.fstr=True 

        self.repaint()

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.Enter:
            self.paused = True
        elif event.type() == QEvent.Leave:
            self.paused = False
        return super().event(event)
    def getColor(self)->QColor:
        if self.styleSheet()=='':
            return QColor("grey")
        else:
            style =self.styleSheet().split(";")
            color= "".join([s.split(":")[1] for s in style if s.startswith("color")])    
            return QColor(color)
        
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        if self.document:
            p = QPainter(self)
            self.getColor()
            p.setPen(self.getColor())
            p.translate(self.x, 0)
            self.document.drawContents(p)
        return super().paintEvent(event)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Marquee()
    w.setFixedSize(250, 60)
    w.setStyleSheet("background-color:black;color:yellow")
    f=QFont()
    f.setPointSize(20)
    f.setBold(True)
    f.setItalic(True)
    f.setFamily("Courier")
    w.setFont(f)
    w.setText("consectggftr_conversion_we want",mode="L+R") # or "RL" or "LR"
```

There is also better version of this Code provided by **@eyllanesc** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505130/creating-a-marquee-effect-in-pyside)

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in Qt that does that by default.  You will indeed need to create an animation that changes the text.

You can use `QFontMetrics` (`label.fontMetrics()`) to determine if the label text is larger than then `QLabel` (to know if you need to scroll it or not).  You need a way to repaint the `QLabel` every half second or so to animate the scrolling.  The easiest way is probably a `QTimer`.  The easiest method would probably be to subclass `QLabel` and have it check if it needs to scroll itself and reset the text every half second or so to simulate the scrolling.

If you wanted scrolling to be even smoother (at a sub-character level), you'd have to override the paint method and paint the text yourself translating and clipping it as necessary.

Comment: This sounds exactly like what I was really wanting to avoid. Thanks, I will just try to find a way to smartly restrict the size of text allowed.

Comment: Qlabels allow wordwrap you know.

Comment: Yes, but we want large font in a fairly small space, don't think word wrapping is gonna work.