# Animating QLabel

Tags: python, animation, pyqt5

I want to have a label with text inside a frame and animate it from right to left and then from left to right and so on...

The main problem is managing the width of QLabel (variable).
I can't use any Layout because the property I animate is the geometry of QLabel.

Here is what I have done:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'untitled.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.0
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QRect

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 58)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.now_playing = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.now_playing.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.now_playing.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.now_playing.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 40))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.now_playing.setFont(font)
        self.now_playing.setStyleSheet("QFrame{\n"
        "background-color:white;\n"
        "border:1px solid #dadada;\n"
        "}")
        self.now_playing.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.now_playing.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.now_playing.setObjectName("now_playing")
        self.now_playing_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.now_playing)
        self.now_playing_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 161, 19))
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.now_playing_label.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.now_playing_label.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Calibri")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.now_playing_label.setFont(font)
        self.now_playing_label.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.now_playing_label.setStyleSheet("QLabel{\n"
        "    border:0px;\n"
        "}")
        self.now_playing_label.setObjectName("now_playing_label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.now_playing, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.now_playing_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Some text which wil be updated..."))


    def animate_now_playing_right(self,ui,MainWindow):
        #time.sleep(1)
        #get text size
        self.now_playing_text_width = ui.now_playing_label.size().width()
        #get now playing frame size
        self.now_playing_frame_width = ui.now_playing.size().width()
        #set start x
        self.now_playing_start_x = 10
        #set end x
        self.now_playing_end_x = self.now_playing_frame_width-self.now_playing_text_width-10

        #set the animation
        self.now_playing_animation_right = QPropertyAnimation(ui.now_playing_label,b"geometry")
        self.now_playing_animation_right.setDuration(5000)
        self.now_playing_animation_right.setStartValue(QRect(self.now_playing_start_x,ui.now_playing_label.y(),self.now_playing_text_width,ui.now_playing_label.size().height()))
        self.now_playing_animation_right.setEndValue(QRect(self.now_playing_end_x,ui.now_playing_label.y(),self.now_playing_text_width,ui.now_playing_label.size().height()))
        self.now_playing_animation_right.start()
        self.now_playing_animation_right.finished.connect(lambda: self.animate_now_playing_left(ui,MainWindow))

    def animate_now_playing_left(self,ui,MainWindow):
        #time.sleep(1)
        #get text size
        self.now_playing_text_width = ui.now_playing_label.size().width()
        #get now playing frame size
        self.now_playing_frame_width = ui.now_playing.size().width()
        #set start x
        self.now_playing_start_x = self.now_playing_frame_width-self.now_playing_text_width-10
        #set end x
        self.now_playing_end_x = 10

        #set the animation
        self.now_playing_animation_left = QPropertyAnimation(ui.now_playing_label,b"geometry")
        self.now_playing_animation_left.setDuration(5000)
        self.now_playing_animation_left.setStartValue(QRect(self.now_playing_start_x,ui.now_playing_label.y(),self.now_playing_text_width,ui.now_playing_label.size().height()))
        self.now_playing_animation_left.setEndValue(QRect(self.now_playing_end_x,ui.now_playing_label.y(),self.now_playing_text_width,ui.now_playing_label.size().height()))
        self.now_playing_animation_left.start()
        self.now_playing_animation_left.finished.connect(lambda: self.animate_now_playing_right(ui,MainWindow))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    ui.animate_now_playing_right(ui,MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What do you mean by *I want to have a label with text inside a frame and animate*? your requirement is not precise, could you explain better

Comment: Do you want to implement the marquee animation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505130/creating-a-marquee-effect-in-pyside?

Comment: @eyllanesc 1. run the above code to see.
2. container_widget=frame, inner_widget=QLabel (text)

Comment: Yes the marquee. I will see the link for further disqussion.